# Rails searchkick displaying results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have searchkick working ( i can see the params displayed with byebug)

However, I'm wanting it to show a results page, ( i do need to create the search results page which im currently doing)

I havent a clue on how to link serch kick up so it spits out the results of the search (pagenated) rather than not showing anything

Heres what i have so far, I have the search engine on the homepage.

**/pages/home.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag search_events_path, class: "form-inline", remote: true, method: :get do %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is in my routes

```
  get 'search_events' => 'newevents#search', as: 'search_events'
```

my controller is this

```
  def search
    events = Newevent.search params[:search]
    render :json => events.to_json
  end
```

And my model just has `searchkick` inside

I'm wanting to have the search results show on a page inside the event folder called results.html.erb. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Please be gentle, I've not been working with rails long. (enough to have read a couple of books thats how i have gotten this far haha!)

Comment: so you want to render result as html, don't you? but I see you write `render :json => events.to_json` so you're forcing this action to render json instead of html right?

Comment: Yep So i need to point this to a search html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want `newevents#search` to render `results.html.erb` inside the `app/views/events` folder. Here you are:

```
def search
  @events = Newevent.search params[:search]
  render 'events/results'
end
```

Comment: Does it matter that the results page is in a different area?, And am i right in thinking that if one of the columns in the database is event_name how do i go about calling it? or is it jsut <%= event_name%>

Comment: Ah I see...So you are trying to render a html view inside `app/views/events/` folder from `NeweventsController`, am I right?

Comment: indeed, I'm wanting result html page to be inside there

Comment: And how do i call the columns with search kick? as with byebug i can just do params

Comment: Although your question is off-topic but I will try to help. Search kick will return you an array of found records, so it depends on how you use it. Try to just print it in plain text, see it here: http://pastebin.com/garBn2Eh

Comment: @Tester123 upvote my answer if it does help you so other can find it easier ;)